# OpenLayers print map

Tags: printing, dictionary, openlayers, geoserver

How can I print a map from the OpenLayers? I want to add print button in my OpenLayers page =) I have MapFish extension for my geoserver, but don`t know how to make request to it. Any other ideas are welcome) Help please.

Comment: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-pdf.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use GeoExt.PrintMapPanel ([geoext example](http://api.geoext.org/1.1/examples/print-preview-osm.html)). And be sure to read [GeoServer Printing Module](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/printing/index.html).

**UPD** GET request example. You must modify url, "baseURL", "layers". If you specify an existing layer, this request must return pdf file.

```
http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/pdf/print.pdf?spec={"units":"degrees","srs":"EPSG:4326","layout":"A4","dpi":75,"mapTitle":"Printing Demo","comment":"This is a simple map printed from GeoExt.","layers":[{"baseURL":"http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms","opacity":1,"singleTile":true,"type":"WMS","layers":["topp:tasmania_state_boundaries"],"format":"image/jpeg","styles":[""]}],"pages":[{"center":[146.56000000001,-41.56],"scale":8192000,"rotation":0}]}
```

Comment: I did it. But not everything works. Geoserver and the site which is working with him are on different servers. The proxy is configured, but does not return to create.json pdf file. In what could be the problem?

Comment: Geoserver printing module is installed properly? Try `http://{geoserver_url}:8080/geoserver/pdf/info.json`;

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. But http://{geoserver_url}:8080/geoserver/pdf/create.json returns: "Error while generating PDF:
Unknown method: /create.json"

Comment: Tried to test [link](http://{geoserver_url}:8080/geoserver/web/?wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.geoserver.printing.PrintDemoPage) pdf returns good.

Comment: This is normal. I updated my answer, try to create a GET request manually. Look at the request status and geoserver log.

Comment: GET not for my case, too much data, I come across the limitation

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem using a reverse proxy, because I discovered the answer from info.json contais local ip reference instead of the public url

to solve brutally i replaced the ip referenze with the public url in the ajax request (see the following code. I hope it can be usefull for others...

```
this.capabilities.createURL = this.capabilities.createURL.replaceAll("192.168.0.0:8080", "mypublicurl");
this.capabilities.printURL= this.capabilities.printURL.replaceAll("192.168.0.0:8080", "mypublicurl");


Ext.Ajax.request({
    url:this.capabilities.createURL,
    jsonData:jsonData,
    success:function(response){
        response.responseText = response.responseText.replaceAll("192.168.0.0:8080", "mypublicurl");
        window.open(Ext.decode(response.responseText).getURL);
  }
});
```